# Another unrecognized token error while using RubyOnRails SQLite3 adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm building a simple Rake task to move new records from an external text file into a Rails model. The task consistently fails as follows:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "'": SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."name" = 'sensitive_data_string_goes_here'
```

The Rails find command is coded as follows:

```
existing_pn_record = Product.where('name' => pn)
```

It seems straightforward. Any hints?

Comment: try  `Product.where(name: 'pn')`

Comment: Thanks @SamD but same result. FYI, using Ruby 1.9.3.p448. And pn is a variable (changes value with each new record read from text file).

Comment: then do `Product.where("name= ?", params[:pn])`

Comment: Interesting. Rake doesn't recognize params as an argument. FYI, the data is not coming from a form submission - it's coming from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to pass a `Symbol` instead of a `String`
In ruby `1.8`, `Product.where(:name => pn)`
In ruby `1.9+`, `Product.where(name: pn)`

Comment: Thanks @MurifoX but same result. Using Ruby 1.9.3, and pn = variable, not constant string. FYI.

Comment: Ops, my bad, removed the quotes around pn.